# drawer not able to handle click events in android

Tags: android

I want to display toast when an item is clicked in the drawer but not display simply closing drawer...

everything is working fine except handling click events.

I am using the following code.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                TitleNavigationAdapter adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(this, items);
                drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
                drawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

                drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                        GravityCompat.START);
                // getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
                getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

                drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                        R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.desc, R.string.refresh) {
                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                        drawerToggle.syncState();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                        getActionBar().setTitle("Opened");
                    }

                };
                drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "seleceted" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Which listener are you using. Use ListView.setonclicklistener directly instead of this.

Comment: even that onItemClick listener is inside onCreate method. I wonder how come it placed there

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` in your class declaration?
Another thing to try is to directly set the onClickListener to a new listener

```
drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Log.d("MyApp", "seleceted" + position);
    Toast.makeText(this, "seleceted" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
```

Also I recommend using the Log for sending debug messages during development.

Answer (score 0):

Insert drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList); inside onItemCLick(...)

@Override

public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

```
       drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, "seleceted" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```